# MonoTouch running NSTimer even when app is in background

Tags: background, xamarin.ios, nstimer

In my app i want to run the Timer even when app goes in the background. I guess there are two ways to do it

1. Using thread
2. Capturing time when app goes in background and comes back

I dont know which way is better? If i use threading, then for how long does it works? Does it work for hours in background?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're app entered to background state, you have not too much time to stop current threads.

You could run background task like that:

```cs
...
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    ...
    public override void DidEnterBackground (UIApplication application)
    {
        int taskID = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask ( () => {});
        var task = new Thread (new ThreadStart (() => { 
            // Save application's current state.
        }));
        task.Start ();
    }
```

Thus you'll have up to **`10 minutes`**.

Yet `iOS` doesn't allow to run app infinite time. See [BackgroundExecution](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/BackgroundExecution/AppDelegate.cs) demo for reference.

Comment: Does that mean i wont be able to run a task(Timer in my case) in background for more than 10 mins.

Comment: You could do that, but `iOS` doens't guarantied that app stay alive.

Comment: Another way is to register app, which might do some special operations like `playing background audio`, `using VOIP services`. Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3, paragraph `Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks`.

Comment: For best understanding of multitasking and background working in iOS I recommend to read relevant chapter 11 `"Multitasking"` in book http://www.amazon.co.uk/Developing-Apps-iPhone-using-MonoTouch/dp/1430231742/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1368038219&sr=8-4&keywords=monotouch